# Why is Fallback function not being executed?

Tags: solidity, contract-development, payable

I have a fallback function for receive ether on my contract and I have a function for send ether to my contract, also in my contract, I have withdrawal function.

Why is the fallback function not executed when I executed `paybaleFunction()`?
I detected this case with help withdraw function, which sends ether from contract `this.balance` to my address.

```
contract Some {
   function () payable {
      withdraw();
   }
   function withdraw(){}

   function paybaleFunction() payable{
      withdraw();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fallback function does not execute because fallback function works if a transaction hasn't parameters which have a name of call functions.
When I call `paybaleFunction()` my transaction which send to the contract have parameter which point on `paybaleFunction()`.
More detail about this on [Fallback Function](https://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#fallback-function)

Answer (score 1):

What error are you getting?
Notice that the code pasted above won't even compile as `withdraw(){}` should be properly written as `function withdraw(){}`

Running the contract as follows does work (in the sense that withdraw does get called in both cases):

```
contract Some {
   function () payable {
      withdraw();
   }
   function withdraw(){
       //some code
   }

   function paybaleFunction() payable{
      withdraw();
   }
}
```

Comment: I haven`t error. I want know why is it executed?

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because your fallback function calls the function `withdraw()` but your withdraw function does not contain any code. Try changing this code to your withdraw function:

```
function withdraw(){
       msg.sender.transfer(this.balance);
   }
```

Comment: thanks, but my code it is a pattern for example.